# Error connecting MongoDB with Symfony 5.2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I am trying create a database using MongoDB in my Symfony 5.2

When I add in my .env this

```
###> doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle ###
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017
MONGODB_DB=symfony
###< doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle ###
```

with the `DATABASE_URL` var by default (if I change postgresql to mongodb, it says driver not found)

`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"`

I have this error

```
Connection does not contain a 'path' or 'dbname' parameter and cannot be created.
```

If I comment the var `DATABASE_URL`. I got

```
Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_URL"
```

My `doctrine_mongodb.yaml`:

```
#config/packages/doctrine_mongodb.yaml

doctrine_mongodb:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    auto_generate_hydrator_classes: true
    connections:
        default:
            server: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_URL)%'
            options: {}
    default_database: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_DB)%'
```

I am executing this command `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

I didn't see many solutions for this trouble here

Comment: Do you have `doctrine/orm` still installed? You should not have a reference to `DATABASE_URL` when you only use `doctrine/mongodb-odm` and its bundle. I don't think there is a `doctrine:database:create` command either with the mongodb-odm-bundle. To me it looks like things are mixed up a bit from your old postgres-setup. Could you edit your question to make clear what your current setup with postgres looks like, what steps you took to move to mongodb and what you are trying to do? That will help us identify where things get mixed up between both systems

Comment: @dbrumann Yes i have doctrine/orm i am upgrading my symfony 3 to 5. I never had installed postgres, it is the default installation update.

Comment: Ok, now I am extra confused you never have used a relational database? You want to use mongodb? If so, then the problem is likely that Symfony defaults will guide you towards doctrine/orm, which is for "classic" databases like mysql or postgres. I think the easiest way to fix the config, is by removing all doctrine packages from your composer.json and running `composer install`. This should also remove the packages and their configs. If not, remove the configs (config/packages/doctrine.yaml, also look in the subdirs). Then run `composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle`